# Selecting, ordering and renaming columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dplyr

I'm trying to find out `R's select` function equivalent in pandas. There is a [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_r.html) for basics but it is not giving a guide what I want to do!

```
raw_data = {'patient': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
        'obs': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
        'treatment': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        'score': ['strong', 'weak', 'normal', 'weak', 'strong']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['patient', 'obs', 'treatment', 'score'])


df.rename(columns = {'treatment':'treat'},inplace=True)


df = df.loc[:, ['treat','score','obs']]

Out[89]: 
   treat   score  obs
0      0  strong    1
1      1    weak    2
2      0  normal    3
3      1    weak    1
4      0  strong    2
```

We can do this with `R's` `dplyr`

```
select(df, treat=treatment, score, obs)  that's it.
```

How can I do this with pandas just one line of code doing selecting, ordering and renaming ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent in pandas for select and rename in one method, is necesarry use similar like your solution:

```
df = df.rename(columns = {'treatment':'treat'})[['treat','score','obs']]
#alternative
#df = df[['treatment','score','obs']].rename(columns = {'treatment':'treat'})
print (df)
   treat   score  obs
0      0  strong    1
1      1    weak    2
2      0  normal    3
3      1    weak    1
4      0  strong    2
```

Answer (score 2):

Now you can do it in the `dplyr` way in python:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tibble, select
>>> 
>>> raw_data = tibble(
...     patient=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
...     obs=[1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
...     treatment=[0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
...     score=['strong', 'weak', 'normal', 'weak', 'strong']
... )
>>> # In python, keyword arguments have to come last
>>> # we specify score=f.score to keep the name unchanged
>>> select(raw_data, treat=f.treatment, score=f.score, obs=f.obs)
    treat    score     obs
  <int64> <object> <int64>
0       0   strong       1
1       1     weak       2
2       0   normal       3
3       1     weak       1
4       0   strong       2
```

I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.